# Acquia Dev Desktop MySQL database troubleshooting on Mac OSX 10.11

Tags: acquia-dev-desktop

I changed the Acquia Dev Desktop configuration, then when Apache web server and MySQL were restarting MySQL never got back online.

I have enabled the debug option in Acquia Dev Desktop.
The logs don't show any clues:

- `/Applications/DevDesktop/piscript.log`
- `/Applications/DevDesktop/mysql/data/mysql.err`

**Workaround**

I am using the MAMP mysql in the meanwhile, it has this convenient shell script:

`/Applications/MAMP/bin/startMysql.sh`

Comment: _I changed the Acquia Dev Desktop configuration_ What did you change? Did changing it back not fix the problem? We're gong to need more details

Comment: I changed the port of the web server to 80. My current configuration is apache on port 80 and mysql on port 33070 (I tried changing this, but it hasn't work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manually starting the MySQL server:

`/Applications/DevDesktop/mysql/bin/mysqld --defaults-file=/Applications/DevDesktop/mysql/my.cnf`

Viewing the log:

`tail -50 /Applications/DevDesktop/mysql/data/mysql.err`

If everything went right you should see the MySQL green dot in the Acquia Dev Desktop GUI.

Answer (score 1):

After spending time on searching for the solution. Below solution worked for me.

Open my.ini (my.cnf on linux-based systems and Mac)

Look for [mysqld]

Just below [mysqld] insert innodb_force_recovery = 1

Start MySQL Service

Stop MySQL Service

Remove the line from my.ini (innodb_force_recovery = 1)

Start MySQL Service